# Populate HTML table with array data

Tags: php, html, arrays, html-table

I need to create and populate a table with a array... for now with some help from the bloggers goes like this:

```
<?php
$details = array(
  1 => array(
      1 => 1000,
      2 => 'Company A',
      3 => '2014-05-10',
      4 => '10:00:00',
      5 => '15:00:00',
  ),
  2 => array(
      1 => 2000,
      2 => 'Company A',
      3 => '2014-05-11',
      4 => '10:00:00',
      5 => '15:00:00',
  ),
  3 => array(
      1 => 3000,
      2 => 'Company B',
      3 => '2014-05-10',
      4 => '10:00:00',
      5 => '15:00:00',
  ),
  4 => array(
      1 => 4000,
      2 => 'Company B',
      3 => '2014-05-11',
      4 => '16:00:00',
      5 => '19:00:00',
  )
);

// Format our data into something we can use more easily
$flight_dates = array();
$times = array();
$dates = array();
foreach ($details as $flight_details) {
  $company_name = $flight_details[2];
  $date = $flight_details[3];
  $time = $flight_details[4] . ' - ' . $flight_details[5];

  // Keep a unique record of each date, and the times of flights
  $dates[$date] = 1;
  $times[$time] = 1;

  // Record which date/time each company is flying
  $flight_dates[$date][$time][] = $company_name;
}

// Create the table header
$html = '<table border="1">';
$html .= '<thead>';
$html .= '<tr>';
$html .= '<th>&nbsp;</th>';
foreach ($dates as $date => $value1) {
  $html .= '<th>' . $date . '</th>';
}
$html .= '</tr>';

// Create the rows in the table
foreach ($times as $time => $value1) { // Loop through each flight time
  $html .= '<tr>';
  $html .= '<td>' . $time . '</td>'; // The first column is always the time
  foreach ($dates as $date => $value2) { // Loop through each date
      if (!empty($flight_dates[$date][$time])) { // Check if flights exist at the current time
        $html .= '<td>' . implode(', ', $flight_dates[$date][$time]) . '</td>'; // List companies
      } else { // No flights
        $html .= '<td>&nbsp;</td>'; // Leave cell blank
      }
  }
  $html .= '</tr>';
}
$html .= '</table>';

echo $html;
?>
```

The result is this:

```
|....................|.. 2014-05-10 ........| 2014-05-11|
|10:00:00 - 15:00:00 | Company A, Company B | Company A |
|16:00:00 - 19:00:00 |......................| Company B |
```

I'm looking to get this:

```
|....................|2014-05-10 | 2014-05-11|
|10:00:00 - 15:00:00 | Company A | Company A |
|10:00:00 - 15:00:00 | Company B |...........|
|16:00:00 - 19:00:00 |...........| Company B |
```

In my idea the deal is: `$times` should have all the times for all the `$flight_details` array, and then we populate, will create a row for each `$times` record, that way we don't need to implode, just put the direct value off the array. The problem is to achieve this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want such format, first off, you need to separate the headers, `2014-05-10 ... etc` since they are above. Then you need to take care of the format. The key is: every time slot assign it to the company. Consider this example:

```
<?php

$details = array( 1 => array( 1 => 1000, 2 => 'Company A', 3 => '2014-05-10', 4 => '10:00:00', 5 => '15:00:00', ), 2 => array( 1 => 2000, 2 => 'Company A', 3 => '2014-05-11', 4 => '10:00:00', 5 => '15:00:00', ), 3 => array( 1 => 3000, 2 => 'Company B', 3 => '2014-05-10', 4 => '10:00:00', 5 => '15:00:00', ), 4 => array( 1 => 4000, 2 => 'Company B', 3 => '2014-05-11', 4 => '16:00:00', 5 => '19:00:00', ), 5 => array( 1 => 5000, 2 => 'Company C', 3 => '2014-05-10', 4 => '10:00:00', 5 => '15:00:00', ), 6 => array( 1 => 5000, 2 => 'Company D', 3 => '2014-05-12', 4 => '10:00:00', 5 => '15:00:00', ),);

//properly sort the raw data
// get headers
$header_dates = array();
foreach($details as $value) {
    $header_dates[] = $value[3];
}

$header_dates = array_unique($header_dates);
// reformat main data companies
foreach($details as $key => $value) {
    $time = "$value[4] - $value[5]"; // use this as key
    foreach($header_dates as $date) {
        // simple initialization
        if(!isset($final[$value[2]][$time][$date])) $final[$value[2]][$time][$date] = '';
    }

    $final[$value[2]][$time][$value[3]] = $value[2]; 
    // then set them accordingly to their date and time
}


?>

<!-- format them inside the table -->
<table border="1" cellpadding="10">
    <!-- print the headers -->
    <thead><tr><td></td><?php foreach($header_dates as $value): ?><th><?php echo $value; ?></th><?php endforeach; ?></tr></thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach($final as $key => $data): ?>
        <?php foreach($data as $index => $element): ?>
            <tr><td><?php echo $index; ?></td> <!-- loop they time -->
                <?php foreach($element as $v):?>
                    <td><?php echo $v; ?></td> <!-- values (Company A, ...) -->
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[**Sample Output**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ATNNO5)

Answer (score 0):

For the result to come like your expected one, you need to give:

```
<td>{explode("," $company_name)[0]}</td>
<td>{explode("," $company_name)[1]}</td>
```

In the headers, you need to give this way:

```
<td colspan="2">{$date}</td>
```

> ***Note:*** The code I have provided is just a pseudo code. You need to write your own code. We can just guide you!

Comment: True, the code must be writen by me, but what is te meanig of SO ? Help with some ideas, and that is just what i'm looking for.... the solution you propose almost works... my problem is to create a new row for every timelapse...

Comment: Help with the code, not write the code fully. I just gave a note, for people not thinking my code doesn't work. Don't worry, nothing offensive! :)

Comment: As I said, works but for the case I can't use that idea for my code... my problem is other, creating 1 row for each timelapse.